# What is the meaning of detour in the following sentences?

Tags: meaning-in-context

Other than a longer route than usual i couldn't find any other figurative meaning to this word in most dictionaries. So can someone explain the meaning to me -

Sentences

1. There’s plenty of time, life has so many detours.
2. Do you see this job as a detour from your ambition?
3. Could you take me on a detour in American history?

I kind of half-understood this thing.

Could someone please elaborate ?

Answer (score 1):

Detour means (from Cambridge Dictionary):

> A different or less direct route to a place that is used to avoid a
>   problem or to visit somewhere or do something on the way.

But in your sentences the word is being used in the figurative sense. In sentence one it means: There’s plenty of time in life because there are many twists and turns in one's life.

In second one it means: Do you see this job as a separate thing from your interests and ambitions?

In third it means: Could you explain me the American history by taking a long or a [roundabout](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/roundabout) route.

Answer (score 0):

The original poster is correct that the literal meaning of "detour" usually means "a longer route than usual, because the usual route is impractical or unavailable".

Sometimes the literal meaning of detour will involve a shorter route.  For example, suppose a highway follows a river around a mountain chain.  Suppose the river is flooded, so the highway cannot be used.  A detour might go through the mountains, and so be shorter.

Each of the original poster's examples are mostly correct.

The first example would be better with a semi-colon, instead of a comma.  Also, this usage of "so many" is informal, whereas this example is formal.  This usage of "detour" is common:

> There’s plenty of time; life has many detours.

The second example is also a common usage of "detour".  I would expect a different word or phrase instead of "ambition".

In the third example, I would expect the word "tour" instead of "detour". But if you were already on a figurative "tour" (of English history, or of origami, *et cetera*) and the discussion of American history would be a "side-trip", then the word "detour" makes sense.  I expect a phrase like "tour of" or "detour through" or "detour into" instead of "detour in".

> Could you take me on a detour into American history ?

Answer (score 0):

Okay, let's assume that the person saying these sentences is named Mary, and that she is talking to John.

> 1. There’s plenty of time, life has so many detours.

Mary is saying that it is okay for John to not follow life's path in a straight line. For example, if John plans on going to college right after high school, but he ends up meeting a girl and having a baby with her, he may be disappointed that he never continued his education. Mary remarks that life is like that; life is unplanned and unexpected "detours" happen. John could go to college later in life if he wanted to.

> 2. Do you see this job as a detour from your ambition?

Let's say that John wants to be an actor (his ambition is to be an actor), but he instead takes a job as a music teacher. Mary is worried that John could be wasting his time on this music job (like a long detour on a road would) instead of following his ambitions of becoming an actor.

> 3. Could you take me on a detour in American history?

Let's say John is a world history teacher, and Mary is his student asking this question. While John normally teaches the history of many countries, Mary would like to talk about American history for a little bit. The class would be going on a "detour" and talk about American history, and then they could "get back on track" and resume talking about major world-wide historic events.